# Unable to write data to table with postgresql OID type

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat6, seam

I'm facing very strange problem with storing data to OID columns on PostgreSQL. The app configuration is:

- Java OpenJDK 64-Bit 1.7
- JBoss Seam 2.2.2.Final
- Hibernate 3.6.4.Final
- PostgreSQL 9.3 (with 9.3-1101-jdbc41 driver)
- Tomcat6
- CentOS 6 as host on production env

This is related to field:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "content", nullable = false, updatable = false)
public byte[] getByteContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setByteContent(final byte[] content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

Configuration in persistence.xml for OIDs:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
```

Field annotated in that way says to postgres dialect it is OID type. As we have to support also MS SQL Server DB it makes it even more complicated since we cannot use any combination of annotations. I cannot make it work on "production" env with postgres, but it works when I run it form IDE - this is very strange. To be more specific data cannot be saved but when data are already stored in postgres (like run from IDE fill DB and reconnect production) it can be read from OID colum. On production I get this error:

```
SeamPhaseListener|ERROR|2014-07-04 12:52:43,550|TP-Processor8|3|swallowing exception
       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not commit transaction
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.commitOrRollback(SeamPhaseListener.java:624)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.commitOrRollback(SeamPhaseListener.java:603)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.handleTransactionsAfterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:344)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:244)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:195)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at com.my.code.servlet.SessionIdFilter.doFilter(SessionIdFilter.java:78)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at com.my.code.servlet.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:61)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at com.my.code.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:80)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
        at com.my.code.servlet.SrmFilter.doFilter(SrmFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.process(RewriteFilter.java:98)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:57)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at com.my.code.servlet.SessionIdFilter.doFilter(SessionIdFilter.java:78)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at com.my.code.servlet.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:61)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at com.my.code.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:80)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
        at com.my.code.servlet.SrmFilter.doFilter(SrmFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
       Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:93)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.EntityTransaction.commit(EntityTransaction.java:110)
        at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.commitOrRollback(SeamPhaseListener.java:612)
        ... 96 more
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ContextualLobCreator.createBlob(ContextualLobCreator.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.unwrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.unwrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$3$1.doBind(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2430)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2874)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
        ... 98 more
```

I have read through a number of tips about Hibernate vs PostgreSQL OID but nothing worked so far. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the DDL for the table from which you need to read OID fields? Why do you need to read them? In some cases it's necessary to read via view and write via stored procedure, or custom SQL queries. ORM's aren't perfect and usually aren't supporting special fields from RDBMS. From what I remember, you are also not expected to write to OID field since this is a special system field.

Comment: You should be using "large objects", use a `bytea` column instead (which is effectively the same as `BLOB` in other DBMS). Search this site. This gets asked about once a month